# Stepping up voltage from solar for a power brick (5V to 15V) possible?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell

i have a 28mAh power brick capable of charging my laptop when charged.
I bought a 28W solar panel which outputs 5V over usb capable of charging ipads etc, however when i connected it to power brick's input it couldnt charge it (or at least charging light didnt come on)
Its only then i realised power brick is running off 15-19V 2A mains charger.
Is it possible to step up my solar panel to this voltage and trickle charge the power brick at all?

Comment: Details of the output circuit of the brick charger would be ideal else it's guesswork.

Comment: 28mAh is very small.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! While yes, it's physically possible to step up a voltage using a switching power supply, you haven't provided enough details to gauge the possibility of charging. Please provide more information about the solar panel, power brick, and mains charger: model number and datasheet or product specifications page. A picture of the device label may help if online details aren't available.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough details so I can't say for sure but it's possible to step up the voltage but it will not help you that you for a simple reason:

your device runs on 15-19 volts 2 amps which means it runs on 30-38 watts but the solar panels output is 28 watts , so if your power brick doesn't work on less than 2 amps or a voltage below 15 volts then it won't work again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need a boost or step-up converter. A step-up converter can increase the voltage (but the power VI is constant.)